# Bypass a PowerShell cmdlet's confirmation prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, confirmation

I am trying to disconnect from a iscsi target from PowerShell using below cmdlet.

```
Disconnect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress $Target.NodeAddress
```

But once i execute that, a confirmation prompt is displayed:

```
Do you want to perform this Action [yes,yestoall,no,notoall,suspend]
```

How can i make default to Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Disconnect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress $Target.NodeAddress -Confirm:$false
```